# Random Stratified Sample in QGIS and Scale

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, scale, sample

I need to sample 7 raster layers all 30 m resolution (as some of the remotely sensed products I'm using are Landsat).

I have all of my layers ready to go, but I am not sure how I can conduct a stratified random sample. The forest I'm interested in has varying forest ages (primarily old) with fewer amounts of younger forests that as shapefiles look like hundreds of small polygons.

Additionally, I have 3 types of geology for the region. If I generate random points using the Random Points tool, I've noticed that I end up with lots of points and may be sampling a pixel more than once, which seems incorrect.

Is there a way for me to sample my raster files. Shouldn't my points be the same size as my pixels? These data will be put into a model I'm building, so having representative samples for these different classes is important.